# Powershell renaming with regex matched group

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm struggling to write a Powershell Command that does the following. Assume A folder which has a bunch of files with random names that match a regex pattern. I would like to capture the part that matches the pattern and rename the file to that part only.

E.g. "asdjlk-c12aa13-.pdf" should become "c12aa13.pdf" if the pattern is `\w\d+\w+\d+` (or similiar).

My current idea looks something like this:

`Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -match $pattern ... } -WhatIf`

where `...` needs to be replaced with something that sets the "value" of the codeblock (i.e. the NewName) to the matched group. I.e. I don't know how to access `$matched` directly after the `-match` command.

Also, I wonder if it's possible to do lazy matching using `-match`, `.*?` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: For the regex you could capture in a group what you want and use those groups in the replacement [`example`](https://regex101.com/r/BRXPzE/1)

Comment: exactly what i had in mind, yes. the powershell poses more of a problem :/

Comment: Heh... random names that match a regular expression. I'm not positive that you know what random means. :)

Comment: @EBGreen possibly poor choice of words, granted. Random in the sense that there is a random part in the filename not governed by the pattern and that the pattern could be anything and that the symbols constituting the pattern can be random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)** rather than [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) to **match *and* extract the parts of interest in a *single* operation**, which requires you to:

- design your [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to match the *whole* input string,
- enclose the subexpressions that match the parts of interest in `(…)`, i.e. *capture* groups
- and refer to those parts in the substitution operand; `$1` refers to what the *first* capture group captured, `$2` the second, and so on.

```bash
Get-ChildItem |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^.*\b(\w\d+\w+\d+)\b.*(\.pdf)$', '$1$2' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: As in your own code, the [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note that input files that don't match the regex are left untouched.
Read on for details.

As for:

> I wonder if it's possible to do lazy matching using -match, `.*?` doesn't seem to do the trick.

The above uses `\b` (word-boundary assertions) as the *more robust* alternative to lazy matching, but `.*?` *does* work in principle, as the following simplified example shows:

```bash
# -> 'c12aa13.pdf'
'asdjlk-c12aa13-.pdf' -replace '^.*?(\w\d+\w+\d+).*(\.pdf)$', '$1$2'
```

That is, the `?` after `.*` ensured that the `c` match was "given up" in order to match the following subexpression, `(\w\d+\w+\d+)`, as early as possible - go to [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/VNMO0G/2) and experiment with removing the `?` to see the difference in behavior.

---

###### Explanation of the `-replace` technique and regex:

While you could follow the `-match` operation in your own attempt with subsequent extraction of the matched part(s) via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), it's often easier to *combine* the two operations with the help of the `-replace` operator:

You just need to make sure that in order to return only the parts of interest, you must match the input string *in full* and then ignore the parts you don't care about, as shown in this simplified example:

```bash
# -> 'c12aa13.pdf'
'asdjlk-c12aa13-.pdf' -replace '^.*\b(\w\d+\w+\d+)\b.*(\.pdf)$', '$1$2'
```

<sup>For a more detailed explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/zlW6Mm/2).</sup>

- `.*\b` matches the prefix before the part of interest; `\b` makes sure that the following subexpression only matches at a *word boundary* (i.e. only at a character *other* than an alphanumeric one or `_`).
- `(\w\d+\w+\d+)` matches the part of interest, wrapped in a capture group; since it is the *1st* capture group in the regex, you can refer to what it captured as `$1` in the replacement operand.
- `\b.*`, at a word boundary, matches everything after up to the `.pdf` filename extension.
- `(\.pdf)$` matches filename extension `.pdf` at the end of the name and, as the *2nd* capture group, can be referenced as `$2` in the replacement operand.

  - Note that an alternative to operating on the full `.Name` value including the extension is to match against the `.BaseName` property only and append the `.Extension` property afterwards, along the lines of:

    ```bash
    ($_.BaseName -replace '…','…') + $_.Extension
    ```
- `$1$2` simply concatenates the 2 capture-group matches to output the desired name.

  - Note: Generally, use *single-quoted* strings for both the regex and the replacement operand, so that `$` isn't accidentally interpreted by *PowerShell* beforehand.
  - For more information about `-replace` and the syntax of the replacement operand, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

Answer (score 2):

A safer method is to do so with a test (similar to `-WhatIf`)
This example renames files from `DSC12345 - X-1.jpg` => `DSC12345-X1.jpg`

```
# first verify what your files will convert too
# - gets files
# - pipes to % (foreach)
# - creates $a variable for replacement
# - echo replacement
Get-ChildItem . | % { $a = $_.name -replace "^DSC(\d+)\s-\s([A-Z])-(\d).jpg$",'DSC$1-$2$3.jpg'; echo "$_.name => $a"; }

# example output:
# DSC04975-W1.jpg.name => DSC04975-W1.jpg
# DSC04976-W2.jpg.name => DSC04976-W2.jpg
# DSC04977-W3.jpg.name => DSC04977-W3.jpg
# ...

# use the same command and replace "echo" with "ren"
Get-ChildItem . | % { $a = $_.name -replace "^DSC(\d+)\s-\s([A-Z])-(\d).jpg$",'DSC$1-$2$3.jpg'; ren $_.name $a; }
```

This is much safer as renames can be disastrous when run incorrectly.

Comment: Using `-WhatIf` _is_ safe - and there's no reason to re-invent it. Combining `-WhatIf` with a `-replace` operation to _preview_ the results, as in the accepted answer, is sufficient.

Comment: i think the difference is i prefer to get a visual log of the change.

Comment: `-WhatIf` provides display output by design - or are you referring to wanting to control _the specific format_ of these what-if messages (which `-WhatIf` gives you no control over)? If so, I suggest framing your answer accordingly. The "A safer method" part is misleading.

Comment: P.S.: To visualize what happens when you perform the actual renaming, i.e. without `-WhatIf`, you can use `-Verbose` (which in essence prints the same message as `-WhatIf`).

Answer (score 1):

You can put as much as you want in the scriptblock.  Also hiding the output of the -match.  The regex is lazy with the "?".

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { [void]($_.Name -match '.+?'); $matches.0 } -WhatIf

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/afile Destination: /Users/js/foo/a".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/bfile Destination: /Users/js/foo/b".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/cfile Destination: /Users/js/foo/c".
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am not sure if your line above will work. If "\w\d+\w+\d+" is the pattern you are looking for, I would do something like this:

```
[regex]$regex = "\w\d+\w+\d+"    
Get-ChildItem | ?{$_.name -match $regex} | %{rename-item $_ "$($regex.Matches($_).value).pdf"}
```

In this case, you pipeline the output of the Get-ChildItem to the "foreach where loop" (?{...}), and after that you pipeline this outpout to the "foreach loop" (%{...}) to rename every object.